# How to get the proper output in the C Program?

Tags: c

I am doing a simple multiplication in this code. I have initialized integer a = 200000 and b =100000 which is well within the limit of integer range. When I tried to store the multiplied value of a*b in a long integer c. It is not showing the desired result until one of the variables a or b or both are changed into long integer data type. I am using a 64-bit compiler. The sizeof(int) is 4 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 200000;
    int b = 100000;
    long long c = a*b;
    printf("%lld",c);
    return 0;
}
```

I have even tried multiple compilers and the output is -1474836480 which looks like out of range output but I need to know why this thing occurs.

Comment: Please don't tag C questions as C++. They are not the same language.

Comment: When you are multiplying two integer they can only hold max value of int else you type case them to long long.

Comment: "well within the limit of integer range" - Don't confuse "integer" and `int`. There are several integer types. `int` is just one of them.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2). Your integers are promoted at most to `unsigned` and any value that exceeds the range of `unsigned` is reduced modulo to fit within `unsigned`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long long c = a*b;
```

`a*b` is evaluated as the multiplications of two `int` values. The result of this operation is also an `int` (causing the overflow) which is then implicitly extended to `long long` before being stored in `c`.  The problem here is that the extension occurs *after* the multiplication.

Explicitly extending either `a` or `b` to `long long` before the multiplication will fix this:

```
long long c = (long long)a * b;
```

As you've noticed, changing the type of `a` or `b` to `long long` also fixes the problem.  It's another way to implement the same solution.

Further reading: [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply an `int` and an `int`, you get an `int` result. Assigning that to a `long` doesn't change that.

When you multiply an `int` and a `long`, you get an `long` result.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 200000;
int b = 100000;
long long c = a*b;
```

`a` and `b` are of type `int`. The values `200000` and `100000` are probably within the range of `int` *on your implementation*, though the standard only guarantees 16 bits (-32767 to +32767).

In almost all cases, the type of an expression in C is determined by the types of its operands, not their values or by the context in which the expression appears. In this case, `a * b` mathematically would evaluate to `20000000000`, which would require more than 32 bits to represent. (On a system with 64-bit `int`, that wouldn't be a problem, but most implementations these days have 32-bit `int`).

`long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide, so it's well able hold that value -- but you have to give it a value of type `long long`. As cdhowie's answer correctly says, converting one or both operands to `long long` should do the trick.

It's hard to tell from this small program, but you should consider the possibility that `a` and `b` should have been of type `long long` in the first place. If you're converting numeric values to wider types, it's sometimes (but by no means always) that the values should have been of that wider type.

Answer (score 0):

Listen statement `long long c=a*b` will be evaluated according to associativity which is left to right. so `a*b` will be evaluated first which means it will be get overflow/(out of range) and loose value after that it will be assigning to `long long c` so variable `c` will have depricaited value of `a*b` due to run time overflow of this evaluation.

**To avoid this you can do two things :**

1. You can declare `a` and `b` both long long type.
2. Or You can type caste like this `long long c=(long long)a*(long long)b;

Both will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
long long c = a*b;
```

In above line first right hand side expression is evaluated first and then assigned to variable 'c' on left hand side.

During evaluation of expression a*b,if 'a' and 'b' are of type int then result is also of type int.

This int result in stored in a variable 'c' of type long long.

So either type cast any one variable in expression a*b to long long or change their datatypes to long long.